# Cannot use environment variables for settings in Django

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

In trying to find a place to store and save settings beyond settings.py and the database, I used an environment.json for environment variables. I import these in settings.py.

My problem is that when I try to change or store new values in my environment, `env`, `settings.py` does not notice the change - perhaps because the time and number of times settings.py is read by Django.

Is there a way I would be able to use my environment variables the way I want like attempted below?

```
# settings.py
import json
with open('/home/dotcloud/environment.json') as f:
    env = json.load(f)
EMAIL_HOST = env.get('EMAIL_PORT', '500')

# views.py
import json
def site_configuration(request):
    with open('/home/dotcloud/environment.json') as f:
        env = json.load(f)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        os.environ['EMAIL_PORT'] = request.POST['email_port']
    return render(request, ...)

# python manage.py shell demo
>>> import json
>>> with open('/home/dotcloud/environment.json') as f:
...     env = json.load(f)
... 
>>> project_settings.EMAIL_PORT
'500'
>>> env['EMAIL_PORT']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'EMAIL_PORT'
>>> env['EMAIL_PORT'] = "123"
>>> env['EMAIL_PORT']
'123'
>>> project_settings.EMAIL_PORT
'500'
>>> project_settings.EMAIL_PORT == env['EMAIL_PORT']
False'
```

And if not, how else could I store changeable settings that are retrieved by `settings.py` somewhere in my Django project?

Answer (score 37):

You might want to look into `foreman` ([GitHub](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)) or `honcho` ([GitHub](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho)). Both of these look for a `.env` file in your current directory from which to load local environment variables.

My `.env` looks like this for most projects (I use dj-database-url for database configuration):

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite://localhost/local.db
SECRET_KEY=<a secret key>
DEBUG=True
```

In your `settings.py` file, you can load these settings from `os.environ` like this:

```
import os
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)
```

If there are required settings, you can `assert` their presence before trying to set them:

```
assert 'SECRET_KEY' in os.environ, 'Set SECRET_KEY in your .env file!'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

I've been using this method of handling local settings for the last few projects I've started and I think it works really well. One caveat is to *never* commit your `.env` to source control. These are local settings that exist only for the current configuration and should be recreated for a different environment.

Answer (score 7):

I see the question changed slightly, the original answers are still below but this one has a slightly different answer:

---

First, make sure you are using the right settings.py (`print 'This file is being loaded'` should do the trick).

Second, personally I would advise against using json files for config since it is less dynamic than Python files, but it should work regardless.

My recommended way of doing something like this:

1. create a `base_settings.py` file with your standard settings
2. create a `settings.py` which will be your default settings import. This file should have a `from base_settings import *` at the top to inherit the base settings.
3. If you want to have a custom settings file, `dotcloud_settings.py` for example, simply add the `from dotcloud_settings import settings` (or `base_settings`) and set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `dotcloud_settings` or `your_project.dotcloud_settings` depending on your setup.

**Do note that you should be very careful with importing Django modules from these settings files. If any module does a `from django.conf import settings` it will stop parsing your settings after that point.**

As for using json files, roughly the same principle of course:

- Once again, make sure you don't have anything that imports `django.conf.settings` here
- Make all of the variables within your json file global to your settings file:

  import json
  with open('/home/dotcloud/environment.json') as f:
      env = json.load(f)
      # A little hack to make all variables within our env global
      globals().update(env)

---

Regardless though, I'd recommend turning this around and letting the settings file import this module instead.

Also, Django doesn't listen to environment variables by default (besides the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` so that might be the problem too.

Comment: Using `putenv()` in the shell doesn’t even change the environment value. There is also this: ”When `putenv()` is supported, assignments to items in `os.environ` are automatically translated into corresponding calls to `putenv()`; however, calls to `putenv()` don’t update `os.environ`, so it is actually preferable to assign to items of os.environ`.“ I think I might have to find another way to dynamically store and alter settings for e-mail.

Comment: Oops... you are right, I will remove that part. The rest of the advice still counts though :)

Comment: Hey, at least I learned some new things about environment variable operations in Python. ;)

Comment: @Kiwi: please look at my updated answer, it should provide help you along a bit :)