# Add django .env settings to uwsgi server

Tags: django, uwsgi

I working with .env file for hide some settings values at my django projects. A part of settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('CVB_DB_NAME', ''),
        'USER': os.environ.get('CVB_DB_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('CVB_DB_PASS', ''),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('CVB_DB_HOST', ''),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('CVB_DB_PORT', ''),
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
CVB_DB_NAME=db
CVB_DB_HOST=localhost
CVB_DB_USER=owner
CVB_DB_PASS=kwaD
```

And I haven't any problem at locall machine, but then push new settings to productions server I got

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value
```

Im using Django2.2, uwsgi, nginx, python 3.7, pipenv
Could anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: are you using django-getenv package for accessing .env params?

Comment: @RajanSharma , no only python os module

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335488/cannot-use-environment-variables-for-settings-in-django

Comment: @RajanSharma i'm used django-getenv package, now all working good